# How to access a particular layer of Huggingface's pre-trained BERT model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

For experimentation purposes, I need to access an Embedding layer of the encoder. That is, assuming Tensorflow implementation, the layer defined as tf.keras.layers.Embedding(...).

For example, what is a way to set 'embeddings_regularizer=' argument of the Embedding() layer in the encoder part of the transformer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the BERT model in the same way as any other model, like so:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if isinstance(layer ,tf.keras.layers.Embedding):
        layer.embeddings_regularizer = argument
```

`isinstance`  checks the type of the layer, so really you can put any layer type here and change what you need.

I haven't checked specifically whether `embeddings_regularizer` is available, however if you want to see what methods are available to that particular layer, run a debugger and call `dir(layer)` inside the above function.

**Updated question**

The TFBertForSequenceClassification model has 3 layers:

```
>>> model.summary()

Model: "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  108310272 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 108,311,810
Trainable params: 108,311,810
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Similarly, calling `model.layers` gives:

```
[<transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertMainLayer at 0x7efda85595d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x7efd6000ae10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7efd6000afd0>]
```

We can access the layers inside `TFBertMainLayer`:

```
>>> model.layers[0]._layers


[<transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertEmbeddings at 0x7efda8080f90>,
 <transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertEncoder at 0x7efda855ced0>,
 <transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertPooler at 0x7efda84f0450>,
 DictWrapper({'name': 'bert'})]
```

So from the above we can access the TFBertEmbeddings layer by:

```
model.layers[0].embeddings

OR

model.layers[0]._layers[0]
```

If you check the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.html) (search for the "TFBertEmbeddings" class) you can see that this inherits a standard `tf.keras.layers.Layer` which means you have access to all the normal regularizer methods, so you should be able to call something like:

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

model.layers[0].embeddings.activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-5)
```

Or whatever argument / regularizer you need to change. See [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/) for regularizer docs.

Comment: Thank you. This approach will not work with TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased"). E.g. model.layers consists of just 3 layers, with model.layers[0] = TFBertMainLayer with no further access to specific layers for Encoder (e.g. Embedding).  Here is the output of model.layers: [<transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertMainLayer at 0x7f1d5628ac90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x7f1d51c04cd0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f1d51c04f50>]

Comment: Thanks a lot again. While I'm able to move close to the goal, what I need to do is to set 'embeddings_regularizer=' parameter for the tokens embedding layer. I see two embedding sub-layers in TFBertEmbeddings, one for tokens and one for positional encodings. What I need to do is to set 'embeddings_regularizer' in the token embedding layer. That is, for this sub-layer  self.token_type_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding( config.type_vocab_size,  config.hidden_size, embeddings_initializer=get_initializer(self.initializer_range), name="token_type_embeddings",)

Comment: Sorry, there are 3 components for embeddings: word embedding, positional, and token type (sentence A or B).  It is word embeddings layer that I need to apply regularization to.

Comment: There's a comment in the documentation stating that it's a 'shared weights' approach, meaning that you can only change the regularisation for the whole embeddings layer, rather than being able to access individual embeddings layers. If this is true then my answer doesn't need changing (unfortunately).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!